# How to interpret "read extensively and intensively for different purposes in varied sources and increasingly demanding texts."?

Tags: meaning-in-context

How to interpret "read extensively and intensively for different purposes in varied sources and increasingly demanding texts" in the following?

> **OBJECTIVES**
>   **TEKS: English 4**
>   The students will:
>
> ***Reading/Comprehension***
>
> - comprehend selections using a variety of strategies.
> - draw upon his/her background to provide connection to texts.
> - draw inferences and support them with textual evidence and experience
> - **read extensively and intensively for different purposes in varied sources and increasingly demanding texts.**

([Source.](http://www.uh.edu/honors/Programs-Minors/honors-and-the-schools/houston-teachers-institute/curriculum-units/pdfs/2009/shakespeare/green-09-shakespeare.pdf))

Should I interpret it as:

> 1. reading in varied sources and demanding texts for different purposes.

Or

> 2. reading intensively for different purposes, which will vary based off the difficulty of the text.

Comment: The most important point here is that the texts should be more and more difficult as you proceed.

Comment: But is it like when I am reading, I should try to achieve different purposes so I will read the same book twice and discern words more carefully. Or it's like when I am reading different texts, I achieve different purposes.

Comment: It might be helpful if you provide a source or a larger excerpt. It is possible that this is an incomplete sentence.

Comment: This is the site http://www.uh.edu/honors/Programs-Minors/honors-and-the-schools/houston-teachers-institute/curriculum-units/pdfs/2009/shakespeare/green-09-shakespeare.pdf

Comment: I think your amendment makes sense but maybe you can also help with my confusion.

Comment: Always include relevant details, like sources.

Comment: @HUN Read my comment again. The 4th objective is to read **texts which are increasingly difficult.** In other words: challenge yourself!

Answer (score 3):

It clearly parses as:

> read ( extensively and intensively ) ( for different purposes ) ( in varied sources and increasingly demanding texts )

By default, the adverbial phrases apply one by one to the verb phrase from left to right. This is confirmed by the nature of the text from which it is taken, which clearly is supposed to list all the myriad ways the students are supposed to read in the TEKS course. In particular:

- The students will read extensively and intensively.
- The students will read for different purposes.
- The students will read varied sources and increasingly demanding texts.

I just noticed that the original sentence has an extra "in", suggesting as I originally suspected that the author of the sentence is not a native speaker of English. "read in varied sources" is **grammatically incorrect**.

Comment: But does "different purposes" link to "in varied sources and texts" or "read extensively and intensively". Please explain.

Comment: @HUN: No. As I said, they modify the current **verb phrase** one by one, starting with "read". But provide the source of the quote.

Comment: the source is in the above comment section.

Comment: So the quoted phrases don't any connection with each other and I just need to read in a way that is intensive, wide, increasingly demanding and has different purposes.

Comment: @HUN: But yes, by default they all modify "read" and can be individually included or excluded without affecting the meaning of the ones included.

Comment: @user21820 This crossed my mind and maybe it was the root cause of the OP's problem. It looks plausible to me that the intended meaning was something like "read extensively and intensively texts that are written for different purposes, (that are) in varied sources, and (that are) increasingly demanding." In other words, the author might've tried to use "for different purposes in varied sources and increasingly demanding texts" as a single noun phrase, and the whole sentence can be reduced to "read extensively and intensively these kinds of texts". ("for different purposes" is ambiguous to me.)

Comment: @DamkerngT.: But "texts" appears in the sentence at absolutely the wrong place for that to be the case. Each of the other bullet points are also in rather broken English or missing punctuation! The simplest explanation is that the author is not fluent in English. =)

Comment: @DamkerngT.: And only now do I realize the sheer irony of this being the description of an **English** course!

Answer (score 2):

In language teaching, extensive reading and intensive reading are technical terms for two different ways of reading.

[Extensive reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensive_reading) is also known as free reading. You usually don't look up words you don't understand but try to infer meaning from context. (You can even skip entire passages that are too difficult.) Extensive reading is promoted as a good way of increasing reading comprehension, for example by linguists such as [Stephen Krashen](http://skrashen.blogspot.de/2014/01/extensive-reading-in-english-as-foreign.html).

[Intensive reading](http://www-tcall.tamu.edu/research/nso/ss/ss_c.html) aims for a high degree of comprehension and is much slower.

So the phrase "read extensively and intensively for different purposes in varied sources and increasingly demanding texts" means that the learner should be able to switch between extensive and intensive reading strategies depending on the nature of the text and the learner's goal(s) in reading that text.